# Why is this Join Table code doesn't return any data in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I tried to use this code for joining tables, and it doesn't return any data in my blade file modal.

```
    public function edit($id)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            $data = DB::table('mytable1')
            ->join('mytable2', 'mytable2.id', '=', 'mytable1.fk_mytable1_id')
            ->join('mytable3', 'mytable3.id', '=', 'mytable1.fk_mytable3_id')
            ->select('mytable1.*','mytable2.*','mytable3.*')
            ->where('mytable1.id','=', $id)
            ->get();
            return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
        }
    }
```

With this code in my blade file

```
   $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/search/"+id+"/edit",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(html){
                $('#emp_id').val(html.data.id);
                $('#lastname').val(html.data.lname);
                $('#firstname').val(html.data.fname);
                $('#update_record').modal('show');
            }
            
        })
    });
```

This is the code in my Route

```
Route::resource('search', SuperAdminController::class);
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain your problem in more details

Comment: You mentioning joining tables, but there's no joining in either of these code samples. Show us the actual code that isn't working, please.

Comment: @TamilSelvanC my problem is, when I use `DB::` query instead of Model, It doesn't return any data in my blade file.

Comment: Replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` to inspect the query (or use Laravel Telescope or the [debug bar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to take a look at it).

Comment: @ceejayoz it's still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Correct. It's a debugging step, to help *you* solve the problem.